# Prove $mn$ and $m+n$ are both even if and only if $m$ and $n$ are both even.

Tags: arithmetic

How should I begin? It is solve like a normal bi-conditional or must it be done a proof by case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really only one case you need to demonstrate in the forward direction, this only requires that you use the definition of a number being even i.e. $n$ is even if $n=2k$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

So to begin try assuming that $mn$ and $m+n$ are both even and either $m$ is odd or $n$ is odd ( there is no need for cases here since the same argument for $n$ will apply for $m$). Try and derive a contradiction.

For the opposite way use the definition of a number being even and prove it directly. 
Hope that helps :)

Comment: Your first line is wrong. "either $m$ is odd or $n$ is odd" **are two cases**!

Comment: When I say proof by cases is not necessary, I am referring to the fact we do not need to prove more than one case, even if another case exists.

Comment: Alright; I thought you had meant it in the logic sense. How about saying "There is essentially only one case.". Anyway it's not enough to use the definition of "even". No matter how you define "odd", you need induction to be able to use it. I know most people gloss over this but if we want to go strictly by definition we've to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

A non-case simple proof:

$(m+1)(n+1)=mn+m+n+1$ is odd, hence $m+1$ and $n+1$ are both odd

Comment: Of what precisely is this a proof?

Comment: It is the proof of $m$ and $n$ are both even given $m+n$ and $mn$ are even. The converse is trivial.

Comment: It actually shows a little more: $mn$ and $m+n$ are of the same parity only if $m$ and $n$ are even.